# Manifold with boundary given as the pre-image of a subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^{n+k} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function of class $C^r$ for $r>1$. If $M = f^{-1}(0)$ and $0$ is a regular value of $f$, then we know (using implicity functions theorem) that $M$ is a $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ without boundary.

Now, let $N = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+k} \ | \ f_1(x) = \ldots = f_{n-1} = 0 \ $and $f_n(x) \geq 0\}$. If the matrix $\left ( \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\right )_{1\leq i \leq n-1, 1\leq j \leq n}$ has rank $n-1$ for every $x \in N$, how can we prove that $N$ is a $k+1$-manifold with boundary and $\partial N = M$?

I assumed (WLoG) that the first $n-1$ collumns of that submatriz of $df$ has rank $n-1$ and tried looking at the function $F(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+k}) = (x_n,\ldots,x_{n+k},f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+k}),\ldots,f_{n-1}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+k}))$ from $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ (open set such that our assumption on the rank remains valid) to $\mathbb{R}^{k+n}$.

Now, we can use inverse functions theorem to create $G \colon W \times V \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k+1}\times \mathbb{R}^{k-1} \to U_1 \subset U$ such that $G$ is a $C^r$ function and the inverse of $F$ when restricted to $U_1$, but I can't write $N \cap V$ nicely enough to conclude that it is a $k+1$ manifold with boundary, even less showing that $\partial N = M$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we know how to parametrize $M^k$ and $N^{k+1}$ separately by the implicit function theorem but then have to combine these two charts so that a submanifold idea is formulated. For example, near $x_0$ on $N$, we have these two chart functions.

$\phi : (N_0^{k+1}, x_0) \to (U \subset \mathbb{R}^{k+1}, 0)$

$\psi : (M_0^{k}, x_0) \to (V \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}, 0)$

Let $\phi_1$ be the restriction of $\phi$ on $N_0 \cap M_0$. Its image on $U$ is somehow comparable to $V$ in dimension. The next step is to consider
 $\phi \circ \psi^{-1} : V \to U$. We use the submersion theorem to find a diffeomorphism $g$ such that

$(g \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1})(x_1, \cdots, x_k) 
= (x_1, \cdots, x_k, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$.

Ultimately, $g \circ \phi$ provides a better chart for us on $(N, x_0)$. Note that $g \circ \phi_1$ is completely determined by $g \circ \phi \circ \psi^{-1}$.

For the time being, I skip all the restriction on domain in concern.

Reference: Differential Topology from John Milnor.

Comment: Thank you for your time Tony. Actually it seems that we use different definitions for manifolds with boundaries, I'm using Spivak/Munkres definition for manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Comment: I perceive the manifold with boundary as one having this kind of chart along the boundary point, $\phi : (U,x_0) \to \mathbb{H}^n$. Boundary points must be mapped to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^n$. So far there are two ways to state the definition, one is using Whitney extension theorem to make a chart function itself differentiable. Another one just regards transition functions as differentiable in usual sense.

Comment: By the implicit function theorem on $N$ we get $F \circ g: (x_{n}, \cdots x_{n+k}) \to (f_1, \cdots f_{n-1}) $ being the zeros map. Do the same on $M$ and get $F \circ h: (x_{n+1}, \cdots, x_{n+k} \to (f_1, \cdots, f_n)$ being the zero map. We then consider the map $g^{-1} \circ h $, and make it as an inclustion map: $(\Phi \circ g \circ h)(x_{n+1}, \cdots, x_{n+k})=(0,x_{n+1}, \cdots, x_{n+k})$. The map $\Phi \circ g^{-1}$ defines a chart on $N$ near $x_0$, since $F \circ g \circ \Phi = (0, 0 , \cdots, 0, f_n)$.